# Pulling current stock price (Yahoo) with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, stock

I'm having issues using beautiful soup (python3) to pull the latest stock price

[image]

```
import requests
from money import Money
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

response = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VTI?p=VTI")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
price = soup.find('span', attrs = {"data-reactid": "34"})
```

This brings back a value of "None". Is there something that I'm missing? Using a different page, the following worked just fine:

```
response = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup?s=VTI")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")
price = soup.find('td', attrs={"data-reactid": "59"})
```

Unfortunately, that search page doesn't always have a perfect match on the first result (searching VXUS brings back vxus as the 2nd result instead) so I'm hoping to find something that works consistently, and i figured pulling from the actual page would work best.

What would be the best way to pull the 141.28 value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

response = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VTI?p=VTI")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
price = soup.findAll('script')
regularMarketPrice

a = price[-3].contents[0]

jjj = json.loads(a[111:-12])

jjj['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['StreamDataStore']['quoteData']['VTI']['regularMarketPrice']
```

this may help you, first get the scriptdata, then turn it into json, you can find the data you want

Comment: the method @Robert Carlos is more useful if you just want the stock price right now

Answer (score 3):

The price is there and selectable by class (second fastest selector method after id)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

res = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VXUS?p=VXUS')   # https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VTI?p=VTI
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
price = soup.select_one('.Trsdu\(0\.3s\)').text
print(price)
```

Comment: There is no hardcoded index in this solution moreover it is clean and concise. I suppose this should be the chosen one.

Comment: @QHarr - what's the function of the starting period in `'.Trsdu\(0\.3s\)'`?

Comment: @JackFleeting It’s a css class selector

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


response = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VTI?p=VTI")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

for stock in  soup.find_all('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)'):
    print(stock.get_text())
```

This will return 141.28

Answer (score 0):

so its a work around, but since this is just a project for fun, the following works to get the right answer (although i'd prefer a proper, expandable solution)

```
response = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup/etf?s=vxus")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")
price = soup.select('table td')
print(price[2].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for me, but the element within the `class_` might change if the website elements are updated, so I would copy and paste the most up-to-date element from the website inspection if the solution failed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

res = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SQQQ/')   
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
for stock in soup.find_all('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'):
    print(stock.get_text())
```